# MongoDB and Java 8 Time API Grails

Tags: mongodb, datetime, grails, java-8, grails-orm

Searching the documentation of MongoDB I would like to know if it is possible and how to use the Date/Time Java 8 API to store dates in MongoDB, in Grails

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe [this blog](http://www.diogogmt.com/java-8-time-packaged-with-jongo-and-mongodb-dates/) helps.